# Objective c: proximity sensor detection while the screen is locked

Tags: objective-c, iphone, detection, proximitysensor

We are using the proximity sensor to detect whether or not the phone is in the pocket (our application runs on background). But, we have encountered an issue: the proximity sensor state is always false after the user puts his/her phone in the pocket (the screen is locked). Could anyone tell me is it possible to get proximity sensor state while the screen is locked? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on iOS. See **Table 3-1** in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for a list of possible background operations in iOS.